# user deletion and re-addition causing issues

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, system-restore, windows-domain

On a windows server 2003 system I accidentally deleted a user account and immediately re-added it.  Now on her local machine the profile is being ?corrupted? [and creating a temporary profile] running a system restore on her local machine fixes it for a couple of days but then it does it again.  I completely removed and recreated her account on her local win XP machine twice [once right after I deleted the account and once after this happened the first time] and that did nothing either time.

any ideas as to how to make this stop would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Is this a domain or workgroup?

In a domain.

Deleting and recreating the account on the 2003 server creates a new user, no matter if the name is exactly the same. The client machine already has a profile for the old user, so when she logs on it creates the temp profile, because the names are the same.

Logon to the client machine as admin and rename the old user profile. Log the user back on. The new profile should create. you will then need to copy user info from old profile to new one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did that the first time and then a second time the first time the error message popped up during logon

Comment: Is this a domain??

Comment: yes domain.local

Comment: OK. Not sure what you mean by "I completely removed and recreated her account on her local win XP machine". There shouldn't be an account on the local machine. In the end I would probably copy the new account on the 2003 server and create a new slightly different logon and have the user start using that account.

Comment: her settings and files on the local machine and there are accounts on the local machine even though their authenticated to the server

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Log into local machine as admin
rename user account with a *.bak or *.old to prevent windows from using that profile when logging in (as its probably corrupted)
reboot machine
login in as user ( her windows will create a "new" profile with the users name
After login, go to the backup profile "username.bak or username.old etc and copy all the files out of that into the new profile "username" that you just logged in as.

If Windows doesn't allow this, log off at this point. Login as administrator, then copy files from backup to new profile.

Comment: That is what I did twice It is now creating a temporary profile when she attempts to log on and I am assuming that it is being corrupted for some reason but it is only doing it every couple of days